# org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString and blanks in filepath

Tags: java, url

I am trying to read a file to string using org.apache.commons.io version 2.4 on windows 7.

```
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
  if(protocol.equals("file")) {
  File file = new File(url.getPath());
  String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
}
```

but it fails with:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'C:\workspace\project\resources\test%20folder\test.txt' does not exist
```

but if I do:

```
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
  if(protocol.equals("file")) {
  File file = new File("C:\\workspace\\resources\\test folder\\test.txt");
  String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
}
```

I works fine. So when I manually type the path with a space/blank it works but when I create it from an url it does not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(url.toURI())
```

BTW since you are already using Apache Commons IO (good for you!), why not work on streams instead of files and paths?

```
IOUtils.toString(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
```

I'm using [`IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)). Notice that I pass encoding explicitly to avoid operating system dependencies. You should do that as well:

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Does readFileToString stream the file or does it just put the whole contents into a String variable?

Comment: @thonnor it returns String.  Method  declaration follows:
" public static String readFileToString(File file, String encoding) "

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I have done as you said but doesn't work. Why? see [this screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/LiMCp).